# Replace data in text file via Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I need replace the data in text file. The column name is "CODE" in the text file with UserA, UserB and UserC please refer to the image for data. Any assistance would be appreciated.

I have written replace script but it adds UserA twice (for e.g. useruserA) which I am not sure why. Any assistance would be appreciated. I also need to make the first name column uppercase.

```
  $output = C:\temp\txt
  Import-csv -path c:\temp\.csv | select-object *.@{
  Name = "CODE"
  Expression = {$_.CODE -replace("A", "UserA") -replace ("B","UserB") - 
   replace("C","UserC")}
  } -excludeProperty CODE | export-csv -path output
```

Comment: It maybe easier to pipe the CSV to `foreach-object` and modify each row as required with a traditional if/elseif/else statement.

Comment: Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

`-Replace` will replace all occurrences in a string (AKA any the previous replacement result):

```
'aaa' -replace("A", "UserA")
UserAUserAUserA
```

I would use the [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) for this:

```
Import-csv -path c:\temp\.csv |Select-Object *, @{
    Name = 'Code'
    Expression = { 
        Switch ($_.Code) {
            'A' { 'UserA' } 
            'B' { 'UserB' } 
            'C' { 'UserC' } 
        }
    }
} -excludeProperty CODE |export-csv -path C:\temp\txt
```

Comment: What about the first name column uppercase. I tried using .Toupper() but it does not give me the desired output. any suggestion? Also if I change the input file from .CSV to .TXT it changes the output not sure why?

Comment: PowerShell is case insensitive by nature, so the `.ToUpper()` method has generally no effect on a string comparison. There should be no difference when changing the extension. Anyways, don't use the comments for new questions, either [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73369348/edit)  and improve your original question or ask a new question.

Comment: This is not new question it is there in the initial question about uppercase.